# Get Excel sheet name in SUM 'between:sheets' formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a series of sheets with various names e.g.

```
start, wc 17 Oct,  wc 24 Oct, wc 31 Oct
```

To keep a running total of various numbers in each sheet I am simply using the following in each sheet,

```
=SUM('start:wc 24 Oct'!B1)
```

Then the next sheet is,

```
=SUM('start:wc 31 Oct'!B1)
```

And so on and so forth. I know you can get the current sheet name with `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)`

However is there a way to combine the two

```
=SUM("'start:"&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&'!B1)
```

What is the correct syntax to make the above work, if it is possible?

I have tried using `INDIRECT`

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'start:"&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"'!B1", TRUE))
```

However this keeps throwing up a `#REF!` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to add a list of all the sheets to the `start` sheet.

This can be done dynamically by adding a named range.  In the name manager use the following formula:

```
=GET.WORKBOOK(1)
```

And name it something (I used `test`)

[image]

Then in Start!A1 put:

```
=IFERROR(MID(INDEX(test,ROW(1:1)),FIND("]",INDEX(test,ROW(1:1)))+1,999),"")
```

And drag/copy down.  This will create a list of the sheets in order as they appear in the tabs.

Then use this formula in your desired cell to do the sum:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & INDEX('start'!A:A,MATCH("start",'start'!A:A,0)):INDEX('start'!A:A,MATCH(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),'start'!A:A,0)) & "'!B1"),"<>0"))
```